# Black ops 2 on Xbox

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I just got the Xbox s. The market has black ops 2 and black ops 2 season pass both the same price. If I buy the game with the season pass do I get the game and the season pass. Or just the season pass and I still need to buy the game. Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, if you buy only the Black Ops 2 Season Pass you will **not** get the game included. The store page description should mention it (the German one does).

[image: Requires Call of Duty: Black Ops II (sold separately)] Marked text translated: *Requires Call of Duty: Black Ops II (sold separately).*